# How does the serial monitor know where a string terminates when we use Serial.print instead of Serial.println?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial

EDIT: I thought I had to parse the things coming into the program but the speed it is running at makes it indistinguishable to the eye that the word is being printed piecewise.

I am trying to create a serial monitor in rust using the serialport crate. I am using the following modification of blink code on the uno to test it:

```
void setup() {
  // initialize digital pin LED_BUILTIN as an output.
  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

// the loop function runs over and over again forever
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);
  Serial.print("HIGH");
  delay(700);
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, LOW);
  Serial.print("LOW");
  delay(700);
}
```

with println, I am thinking of just concatenating the received buffers and printing on receiving nl or cr. The serial monitor is doing a pretty good job with how it is able to discern a string if a has ended without NL or CR on running the code. How is it doing that? Here is my code right now:

```
use std::time::Duration;
use serialport;

fn main() {
    let open_port_config = serialport::new("/dev/cu.usbmodem1201", 9600).timeout(Duration::from_secs(10));
    let open_port_result = open_port_config.open();

    let mut port = match open_port_result {
                    Ok(res) => res,
                    Err(_) => panic!("Couldn't open the port")
                };
    
    println!("Data bits: {}", port.data_bits().unwrap());
    println!("Flow control: {}", port.flow_control().unwrap());
    println!("Parity: {}", port.parity().unwrap());
    println!("Stop bits: {}", port.stop_bits().unwrap());

    loop {
        let mut serial_buf: [u8; 8] = [0; 8];
        port.read(&mut serial_buf[..]).expect("Found No data");
        let output = String::from_utf8(serial_buf.to_vec()).unwrap();
        println!("{:?},{:?}: {}", serial_buf, output.trim_matches('\0'), output);
    }
}
```

​

Comment: You could experiment with delays shorter than 700 ms, and see at what point the serial monitor starts concatenating messages together.

Comment: @EdgarBonet I am not really able to clearly make out if messages are being concatenated as I lower the delay. I think I caught a stutter here and there but it looks as though it is printing the entire word / string at one go.

Comment: It is unclear to me, what you mean with discerning strings. The Serial Monitor just reads the byte data from the serial port and outputs it in a textbox. It doesn't know of individual strings, just bytes. What exactly is your problem with your current code?

Comment: please copy the content of serial monitor and paste it into your question ... no screenshots

Comment: the serial monitor should not be adding characters that are not received ... it is not a parser, so it has no knowledge of human meaning of received data ... the answer to your title question is `it does not know`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is: It does not know. Or, if you want to look at it in a different way: Timing and chance.

You simply never stumbled upon the case that you read the serial buffer on the PC side *in the exact moment when the Arduino is in the middle of writing to it*. That special case would be where you read and empty the buffer and output "HI" (followed by newline, because you add it in your code) on your serial monitor; then, during the next loop in your rust code, the remaining characters would be read, outputting "GH".

I'd say that you've been lucky that it always worked so far.

The better way would be to always use `println` on the Arduinos side; and on the PCs side: the rust function to "read until newline" from a serial connection (I'm guessing it exists because it does exist in other standard libraries; I never worked with rust before). This way, you'll have in-band signalling for "the next data block begins HERE".

Comment: If you are building a serial monitor, you are not in control of how it will be used. Some users will fail to systematically add line terminators.